# Can't create restart policy to pass Docker security bench

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm creating the service as:

```
docker service create --restart-condition=on-failure --restart-max-attempts=5 --restart-delay=5s --restart-window=60s nginx
```

The problem is that the container will have MaximumRetryCount set to 0 not 5.
How can I fix that problem to be able to pass security bench?

Comment: No one no ideas?

Comment: Uh ... :-( I'm still waiting for some ideas